# Deploy Sinatra app to heroku

Tags: heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to deploy the basic sinatra app from the [heroku docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack#sinatra). The app appears to be deploying and starting correctly, but I can't see it. What am I missing?

```rb
# Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'

# config.ru
require './hello'
run Sinatra::Application

# hello.rb 
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

I then run:

```
$ bundle install
$ git init
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku open
```

The problem is, all I get is a "Heroku | No such app" error. I then try:

```
$ heroku restart
$ heroku logs
```

the result of which you can see below:

```
2012-11-02T06:19:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2012-11-02T06:19:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2012-11-02T06:19:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 38715`
2012-11-02T06:19:31+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-11-02 06:19:31] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-11-02T06:19:31+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-11-02 06:19:31] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 [x86_64-linux]
2012-11-02T06:19:31+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-11-02 06:19:31] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=38715
2012-11-02T06:19:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: Occasionaly I've had to wait after a push, especially for new apps. How is it now?

Comment: I followed your code exactly and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Hmm I will try again, maybe heroku was acting up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these exact same steps just now, and it works just fine. Not sure what was going wrong before.

Last night I changed it to:

```rb
# hello.rb 
require 'sinatra'

class HelloApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    "Hello World!"
  end
end

# config.ru
require './hello'
run HelloApp
```

and it worked. Not sure why, but it did. Odd.

Comment: Did you not have the `class HelloApp < Sinatra::Base` originally?  If not, that is likely the issue here, you'd be telling it to run `HelloApp` without telling it what `HelloApp` was. You could always try `heroku logs` and check for any error messages.

Comment: The basic 'hello world' app in the link I supplied at the top does not define a class which inherits from Sinatra::Base in hello.rb, and it just calls `run Sinatra::Application` in config.ru, hence my confusion when it didn't work.